# Create command not using adjustbox package for inserting image

Tags: macros, document-classes, exam, questionnaire

I am creating a test question using `exam.cls` and I think it would be different if i will include image in the question. But i dont really know how should I insert it. 
i found a solution code that does exactly what I am expecting but these only compiles in 2012 version of TeXLive. Mine was 2009. Is there other posible solution for this to work in 2009 version? Or is there other possible package inspite of using `adjustbox`?

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcommand*{\Image}[1]{\includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=!,valign=m]{#1}}%
\begin{document}
You can insert image here as
\Image{../activity/ddd}
and your text can continue after it
and spill onto the next line as well, so you can see how this works.
\end{document}
```

Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will put the picture half above and half below the baseline:

```
\newcommand*{\Image}[1]{%
  \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{#1}}%
}
```

The macro uses only standard LaTeX constructions. Of course, `graphicx` must be loaded for `\includegraphics` (but it's a package included in *all* LaTeX distributions since the introduction of LaTeX2e).

If you want a default width for the image, but in some cases you
want to modify it, then

```
\newcommand*{\Image}[2][1cm]{%
  \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}}%
}
```

will allow the syntaxes

```
\Image{../Activity/ddd}      % default width 1cm
\Image[2cm]{../Activity/ddd} % width 2cm
```

If you need to specify other keys to `\includegraphics`, it's better
to pass the whole thing:

```
\newcommand*{\ImageF}[2][]{%
  \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}
```

so you can say

```
\ImageF[width=3cm,height=2in]{imagefile}
```

just as if `\ImageF` was `\includegraphics`.

Comment: `\raisebox` and `\includegraphics` are part of `graphicx` and no standard LaTeX constructions, aren’t they?

Comment: `\raisebox` is provided by the LaTeX kernel, not by `graphicx`; in general I consider standard LaTeX whatever is documented in Lamport's manual and `\includegraphics` is there.

Comment: @egreg: OK, thanks :-) “in general I consider standard LaTeX whatever is documented in Lamport's manual” ok for me – certainly `graphicx` is a standard package – but maybe not for absolute beginners ?!

Comment: Is it possible for the image be modified? Seeing the image will be 1cm width in default I think is fine but if image size can be modified which depends on the decided size of the image would be better. Is it possible? Example `\Image{../Activity/ddd}[2cm]`.